# Converting Bootable CD image in Hybrid bootable image

Tags: usb, operating-systems, iso-image, bootloader, burning

I didn't know how to title this post since neither do I know what the problem is.
I generate a `.iso` file with `genisoimage` containing my hobby OS.
Testing this file with `qemu -cdrom file.iso` works fine but I also want to burn this file to a USB stick. Since I'm on Windows I've always used [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to burn an OSs iso, but with this file I get the following error:

> The image is either non-bootable or uses a boot or compression method that is not supported by rufus

Am i doing something wrong with `genisoimage` or can I do something else to fix this?

PS: The OS uses a custom bootloader witch has been written to the iso.

**EDIT**:

This was the command i used for create the iso:

```
genisoimage -R -J \
    -c boot/bootcat \
    -b boot/boot.sys \
    -no-emul-boot \
    -boot-load-size 4 \
    -o build/myos.iso \
    ./build/iso
```

Searching online i found out that instead of `-no-emul-boot` i should use `-hard-disk-boot` but this returns another error:

> Boot image './build/iso/boot/boot.sys' has no partitions

What i tried was converting the bootloader to a floppy image with dd but nothing changed.

How can I set partitions on that binary file?

**EDIT2**:

As pointed by [Daniel B](https://superuser.com/users/219095/daniel-b) and confirmed by my researches I need to use a hybrid ISO to boot also from USB.
Turns out that `isohybrid <isofile>` should have done the trick but since I'm using my own bootloader it gives this error:

> boot loader does not have isohybrid build/myos.iso  an isolinux.bin hybrid signature. Note that isolinux-debug.bin does not support hybrid booting

Is it possible to include this signature in my own bootloader or does exist some other tool to create a hybrid ISO?

Comment: You might want to try to use imgburn instead of the Linux-based genisoimage. That is the Debian Linux ISO creator which is not even packed into Debian anymore (__split__). Try a Windows software. https://wiki.debian.org/genisoimage

Comment: Additionally you can try the balena etcher instead of rufus. But honestly I am not sure will it behave the same way as rufus or not. Anyway it is worth to try.

Comment: @vssher with the iso generated by imgburn i get the same error on rufus but with the tool suggested by Sysadmin the error is more explicit: "Missing partition table" with both ISOs.

Comment: Unless you have a hybrid ISO image, it will not work when written to regular storage. CD/DVD booting is very distinct.

Comment: Windows natively supports creating bootable ISOs via [`oscdimg`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oscdimg-command-line-options), which is contained with the [Windows ADK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install) - only select Deployment Tools during the install.  Once installed, it'll be located at `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg`

Comment: @JW0914 thumbs up for the tool! it works just like linux's one but on windows and it's perfect for my purpose but it still has the same problem

Comment: @DanielB Can you provide some docs or tutorials on how to create a hybrid ISO image with custom bootloader?

Comment: @Bonfra I’m sorry, I don’t have any in-depth knowledge on the topic. You can investigate [how SYSLINUX does it](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid).